# Retrieving a QStandardItem through QStandardItemModel by searching or key

Tags: c++, qt, qstandarditemmodel

Is there any way to assign a unique key to an entry in a `QStandardItemModel` so that we can check for the presence of that key. If it is present we get the relevant `QstandardItem` ?

**Update:**

Here is what I am trying to do. I have 3 column in my table so so i have 3 `QStandardItem`.
This is the code I am using:

```
QStandardItem* item0 = new QStandardItem("Column1");
QStandardItem* item1 = new QStandardItem("Column2");
QStandardItem* item2 = new QStandardItem("Column3");
```

Now my model is called `model` and I am attaching these to my model as such

```
moddel->setItem(0,0,item0);
moddel->setItem(0,1,item1);
moddel->setItem(0,2,item2);
```

I need to assign a row some unique key so that I could check the model for that key and the model would return the row number. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`setData`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditem.html#setData) function of `QStandardItem` in order to set a custom key for a user defined role, eg

```
#define MyRole Qt::UserRole + 2
myItem->setData(Qvariant(key), MyRole)
```

You can get the data of any index in your model by using the [`data`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/qstandarditemmodel.html#data) call.

```
QVariant d = mymodel->data(anindex, MyRole)
```

Writing a function that checks if a key exists should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by pnezis addresses the storing of a key but not the accessing of a `QStandardItem` from the model. I addressed the storing of data with a `QStandardItem` by sub classing `QStandardItem` as I needed to store a lot of complex data.

To obtain the `QStandardItem` from the model you need to create a `QModelIndex` instance with the row/column and then call `itemFromIndex(index)`
on the model.

My example is taken from a selection callback.

```
QModelIndex& selectedItem = itemsSelected.front();
QStandardItemModel* model = reinterpret_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(tableView->model());
if (nullptr == model)
    return;
QStandardItem *item = model->itemFromIndex(selectedItem);
if (nullptr == item)
    return ;
```